# spring data @query and projection should select only needed fields but this is not a case

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Supposing I have an entity (simplified)

```java
@Entity
FooEntity {
  long id;
  String name;
  int age;
  boolean deleted;
}
```

And I want to use spring projections to select only id and name fields of this entity

So I created first interface and class that implements it

```java
public interface DictionaryInterface {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
}

@Value
class DictionaryObject implements DictionaryInterface {
   Long id;
   String name;
}
```

then I created repository interface with method that makes use of projection interface

```
<T> List<T> findByDeleted(boolean deleted, <Class<T> type);
```

and tried two calls and looked at generated sql

```java
findByProjection(false, DictionaryInterface.class) 
// here sql select includes all fields even those that were not needed (age field)


findByProjection(false, DictionaryObject.class) -> 
// here sql select includes only id and name fields
```

my understanding from reading spring data docs is that behavior should be identical and I must select only needed fields but i clearly see that it is not working

where am I wrong ?